# Azure Applications; How to create a separate authorization page for out of network users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I've been tasked with figuring out a way to make a certain set of Azure users authenticate to a Web Application by accepting/denying a warning message that should be presented before the users are directed to the application itself. The users that should not go through this process are in-network users.. they should be able to input the URL and be presented with a sign-in page and from there they will have access into the application. This has already been configured via Azure AD but the previous issue for out of network users is what i'm having issues with.

My current thoughts on this is to create an a simple authorization page created by an azure function that out of network users will be directed to because the IP addresses will be placed in a conditional access rule to do so. From the simple page the user will be directed to the application or logged out if they choose cancel.

This is just a thought but definitely open to suggestions. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have been interested in an answer for this question I have figured it out. In order to do this I had to create a "Terms Of Use" within Azure Active Directory. This Terms of use consisted of a pdf file containing the information my user needed to view before accept/deny could be clicked. On the "Terms Of Use" was created I then created a custom conditional access policy which included users needing to accept the "Terms Of Use" before being able to access our Portal or Applications. Hope this helps